# How to delete element from reactiveValues in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

How to delete element from reactiveValues()

For example, when I run the code:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui=tableOutput("table1"),
  server=function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues(val1 = 1, val2 =2, val3 = 3)
    values$val1 <- NULL

    output$table1 <- renderPrint(reactiveValuesToList( values) )
  }))
```

The output is:

> $val1 NULL $val2 [1] 2 $val3 [1] 3

Instead of:

> $val2 [1] 2 $val3 [1] 3

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can't you subset in a reactive context after you have transformed it as a list? I understand that reactivevalues are not really lists so you can't treat them as such.

Comment: I want to manipulate the reactive values i.e. update or remove them within observeEvent() function (not sure if it is reactive context or not)

Comment: I believe you can't directly delete an element of reactiveValues (I might be wrong). I would suggest an alternative approach, in which you carry out the `values$val1 <- NULL` operation within `observeEvent` and then in your next reactive context you use something like `if (is.null(values$val1))` to evaluate the course of action. Though, again, depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to delete elements from a reactiveValues object because I am using it to store user-defined list objects that can be quite large individually. My concern is that if the user creates too many such objects in a single session it will cause the app to crash due to insufficient memory.

Comment: @Slavatron did you ever figure out how to do this? I posted a similar question today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261240/shiny-how-to-initialize-empty-reactivevalues-with-an-actionbutton (basically same question as you, but deleting ALL entries inside a `reactiveValues`). Lemme know!

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to use the assignment to NULL to remove values, you can assign the reactive value to be a list. See below for a simple modification to Zygmunt Zawadzki's answer. Then operate on the list in the usual R way to reflect the changes in your data.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("delete", "delete"),
      verbatimTextOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

runApp(list(
  ui=ui,
  server=function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues(data=list(val1 = rnorm(1e7), val2 =2, val3 = 3))

    observeEvent(input$delete,{
      values$data$val1 <- NULL
    })

    output$table1 <- renderPrint({
      res <- capture.output(gc())
      cat(res, sep = "\n")
      # No reactiveValuesToList needed
      # x <- reactiveValuesToList(values)
      length(values$data)
    })
  }))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to addres this:

> I would like to delete elements from a reactiveValues object because I am using it to store user-defined list objects that can be quite large individually. My concern is that if the user creates too many such objects in a single session it will cause the app to crash due to insufficient memory.

When you assign NULL to the value R will remove the element from memory. See the app below - when you click `delete` button the memory is released:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("delete", "delete"),
      verbatimTextOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

runApp(list(
  ui=ui,
  server=function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues(val1 = rnorm(1e7), val2 =2, val3 = 3)

    observeEvent(input$delete,{
      values$val1 <- NULL
    })

    output$table1 <- renderPrint({
      res <- capture.output(gc())
      cat(res, sep = "\n")
      x <- reactiveValuesToList(values)
      length(x)
    })
  }))
```

The two images below show you the state before clicking the `delete`, and after -> note that the value used by R has changed.

Those missing 80mb is the size of the `val1` vector.

```
pryr::object_size(rnorm(1e7))
# 80 MB
```

[image: Before click]
[image: After click]