# Shiny: How to initialize empty reactiveValues with an actionButton?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shiny-reactivity

**Background:** In my app, I have built a pop-up modal wherein users can define variables/parameters and they're subsequently stored in a `reactiveValues()` once an `actionButton` is pressed. This appears to work fine.

[image]

**The problem:** I have a separate `actionButton` which is supposed to clear/empty the `reactiveValues` that holds the inputs above. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work--that is, pressing the button doesn't do anything.

**Minimally-reproducible code:**

```
library(DT)

# UI modules
sidebarCharts <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    p(),
    actionButton(ns("settings"), "Settings", 
                icon = icon("cogs"), 
                width = '100%',
                class = "btn btn-info"),
    p(),
    actionButton(ns("refreshMainChart") ,"Refresh", 
                 icon("refresh"),
                 width = '100%',
                 class = "btn btn-primary"),
    p(),
    textOutput(ns("info"))  # FOR DEBUGGING
  )
}

mainChartUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("mainChart"), width = "100%")
}

# UI module for the 2 buttons in the modal:
modalFooterUI <- function(ns) {
  tagList(
    modalButton("Cancel", icon("remove")),
    actionButton(ns("modalApply"), "Apply",
                 icon = icon("check"))
  )
}

# module server
modal <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Init reactiveValues() to store default values and updated values; https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1588
  rv <- reactiveValues(clicks = 0, 
                       applyClicks = 0,
                       bins = 20,
                       bandwidth = 1)
  
  reactiveBlotter <- reactiveValues()  # Empty reactiveValues()
  
  # DEBUGGING
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste("You clicked the 'Settings' button",
          rv$clicks,
          "times. You clicked the 'Apply' button",
          rv$applyClicks,
          "times. The bin size is currently set to",
          rv$bins,
          "and the bandwidth is currently set to",
          rv$bandwidth)
  })
  
  settngsModal <- function(ns) {
    modalDialog(
      
      withTags({  # UI elements for the modal go in here
        fluidPage(
          # titlePanel("Modal title optional"),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                selectInput(ns("n_breaks"),
                            label = "Number of bins:",
                            choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50),
                            selected = rv$bins, width = '100%'),
                sliderInput(ns("bw_adjust"),
                            label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                            min = 0.2,
                            max = 2,
                            value = rv$bandwidth,
                            step = 0.2, width = '100%'),
                textInput(ns("testInputName"),
                          label = "Name",
                          width = '100%'),
                selectInput(ns("testInput"),
                            label = "Test Input",
                            choices = c('A','B','C'),
                            width = '100%'),
                selectInput(ns("testInput2"),
                            label = "Test Input 2",
                            choices = c('D','E','F'),
                            width = '100%'),
                actionButton(ns("addToRV"),
                             label = 'Add to reactiveValues'),
                p(),
                actionButton(ns("clearRV"),
                             label = 'Clear reactiveValues')
            ),
            mainPanel(
              # "Blotter table goes here.",
              fluidRow(
                DT::DTOutput(ns("blotterDT"))
              )
            )
          )
        )
      }),
      title = "Settings",
      footer = modalFooterUI(ns), 
      size = "l",
      easyClose = FALSE,
      fade = TRUE)
  }
  
  # Sidebar 'Settings' modal
  observeEvent(input$settings, {
    showModal(settngsModal(session$ns))  # This opens the modal; settngsModal() defined below
    rv$clicks <- rv$clicks + 1  # FOR DEBUGGING
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$modalApply, {
    rv$applyClicks <- rv$applyClicks + 1  # FOR DEBUGGING
    rv$bins <- input$n_breaks  # This is where I set the reactiveValues() to those inputted into the modal.
    rv$bandwidth <- input$bw_adjust
    removeModal()  # This should dismiss the modal (but it doesn't seem to work)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addToRV, { 
    req(input$testInputName, input$testInput, input$testInput2)
    reactiveBlotter[[input$testInputName]] <- list(testInputName = input$testInputName, 
                                                   testInput = input$testInput,
                                                   testInput2 = input$testInput2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$clearRV, {
    reactiveBlotter <- reactiveValues()  # This is the part that doesn't seem to work
  })
  
  blotterDf <- reactive({
    do.call("rbind", lapply(reactiveBlotter, FUN = function(x) {
      data.frame(name = x[["testInputName"]],
                 input1 = x[["testInput"]],
                 input2 = x[["testInput2"]])
    }))
  })
  
  output$blotterDT <- DT::renderDT({
    validate(need(length(names(reactiveBlotter)) > 0, 
                   "Add something to the blotter."))
    DT::datatable(blotterDf(),
                  style = 'bootstrap',
                  class = 'table-bordered table-condensed',
                  rownames = TRUE,
                  options = list(dom = 't',
                                 paging = F)
    )
  })
  
  output$mainChart <- renderPlot({
    input$refreshMainChart  # Take dependency on the 'Refresh' buton
    
    hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, 
         breaks = as.numeric(rv$bins),  
         xlab = "Duration (minutes)",
         main = "Geyser Eruption Duration")
    
    dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = rv$bandwidth)
    lines(dens, col = "blue")
  })
  
}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("stackoverflow example"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sidebarCharts("main")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      mainChartUI("main")
    )
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(modal, "main")
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Alright folks, I figured this out after some extensive Google'ing. Here's what I determined:

- You can't "delete" or `NULL`-ify an entire `reactiveValues`. Source: [shiny: How to update a reactiveValues object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803536/shiny-how-to-update-a-reactivevalues-object)
- The workaround is to create a single "dummy" `NULL` list within the `reactiveValues` you initialize and reactively update that (or set it to `NULL` to "delete"). Example: https://gist.github.com/aagarw30/4f10bad8aa94d47e024934350c16f2b8

So in my particular case, here's the updated code (which accomplishes what I want it to do, for now):

```
library(DT)

# UI modules
sidebarCharts <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    p(),
    actionButton(ns("settings"), "Settings", icon = icon("cogs"), width = '100%', class = "btn btn-info"),p(),
    actionButton(ns("refreshMainChart") ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"), width = '100%', class = "btn btn-primary"),p()
    ,textOutput(ns("info"))  # FOR DEBUGGING
  )
}

mainChartUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("mainChart"), width = "100%")
}

# UI module for the 2 buttons in the modal:
modalFooterUI <- function(ns) {
  tagList(
    modalButton("Cancel", icon("remove")),
    actionButton(ns("modalApply"), "Apply", icon = icon("check"))
  )
}

# module server
modal <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Init reactiveValues() to store default values and updated values; https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1588
  rv <- reactiveValues(clicks = 0, applyClicks = 0,
                       bins = 20,
                       bandwidth = 1)

  reactiveBlotter <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)  # Empty reactiveValues()

  # DEBUGGING
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste("You clicked the 'Settings' button", rv$clicks, "times. You clicked the 'Apply' button", rv$applyClicks, "times. The bin size is currently set to", rv$bins, "and the bandwidth is currently set to", rv$bandwidth)
  })

  settngsModal <- function(ns) {
    modalDialog(

      withTags({  # UI elements for the modal go in here
        fluidPage(
          # titlePanel("Modal title optional"),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                selectInput(ns("n_breaks"), label = "Number of bins:", choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = rv$bins, width = '100%'),
                sliderInput(ns("bw_adjust"), label = "Bandwidth adjustment:", min = 0.2, max = 2, value = rv$bandwidth, step = 0.2, width = '100%'),
                textInput(ns("testInputName"), label = "Name", width = '100%'),
                selectInput(ns("testInput"), label = "Test Input", choices = c('A','B','C'), width = '100%'),
                selectInput(ns("testInput2"), label = "Test Input 2", choices = c('D','E','F'), width = '100%'),
                actionButton(ns("addToRV"), label = 'Add to reactiveValues'),p(),
                actionButton(ns("clearRV"), label = 'Clear reactiveValues')
            ),
            mainPanel(
              # "Blotter table goes here.",
              fluidRow(
                DT::DTOutput(ns("blotterDT"))
              )
            )
          )
        )
      }),
      title = "Settings",
      footer = modalFooterUI(ns), 
      size = "l",
      easyClose = FALSE,
      fade = TRUE)
  }

  # Sidebar 'Settings' modal
  observeEvent(input$settings, {
    showModal(settngsModal(session$ns))  # This opens the modal; settngsModal() defined below
    rv$clicks <- rv$clicks + 1  # FOR DEBUGGING
  })

  observeEvent(input$modalApply, {
    rv$applyClicks <- rv$applyClicks + 1  # FOR DEBUGGING
    rv$bins <- input$n_breaks  # This is where I set the reactiveValues() to those inputted into the modal.
    rv$bandwidth <- input$bw_adjust
    removeModal()  # This should dismiss the modal (but it doesn't seem to work)
  })

  observeEvent(input$addToRV, { 
    req(input$testInputName, input$testInput, input$testInput2)

    reactiveBlotter[["df"]][[input$testInputName]] <- list(testInputName = input$testInputName, testInput = input$testInput, testInput2 = input$testInput2)


  })

  observeEvent(input$clearRV, {
    # reactiveBlotter <- reactiveValues()  # This doesn't work
    # lapply(X = names(reactiveBlotter), FUN = function(x) {
    #   reactiveBlotter[[x]] <- NULL
    # })  # This is one way to do it, but the names of the items within the reactiveValues() still remain.

    reactiveBlotter[["df"]] <- NULL
  })

  blotterDf <- reactive({
    do.call("rbind", lapply(reactiveBlotter[["df"]], FUN = function(x) {
      data.frame(name = x[["testInputName"]],
                 input1 = x[["testInput"]],
                 input2 = x[["testInput2"]])
    }))
  })

  output$blotterDT <- DT::renderDT({
    validate(need(length(names(reactiveBlotter[["df"]])) > 0, "Add something to the blotter."))
    DT::datatable(blotterDf(),
                  style = 'bootstrap',
                  class = 'table-bordered table-condensed',
                  rownames = TRUE,
                  options = list(dom = 't',
                                 paging = F)
    )
  })

  output$mainChart <- renderPlot({
    input$refreshMainChart  # Take dependency on the 'Refresh' buton

    hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(rv$bins),  
         xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser Eruption Duration")

    dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = rv$bandwidth)
    lines(dens, col = "blue")
  })

}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("stackoverflow example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sidebarCharts("main")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      mainChartUI("main")
    )
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(modal, "main")
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note, I initialize the `reactiveBlotter` object with an entry for `df = NULL` and then reference this as `reactiveBlotter[["df"]]` throughout the rest of the code snippet and it works.